# Setting up GeoIP Blocking on Kong Gateway via Docker

Tags: docker, api-gateway, geoip, konga, ip-blocking

I'm attempting to configure GeoIP blocking on Kong Gateway running in a Docker container. My goal is to block requests from specific geographical regions.

Environment Details:

Operating System: Ubuntu
Docker Version: 24.0.7
Kong Gateway Version: 3.5.0.2

I researched some ways to implement GeoIP, but I only found a plugin that I couldn't configure correctly. I would like to configure blocking based on a blacklist from https://www.iblocklist.com/ and https://iplists.firehol.org/.

How can I perform this operation?

I try to install https://github.com/newageio/kong-plugin-geoip/blob/master/README.md
but i get a error and I cannot install the plugin in Konga